# Custom Action Stop Navigation In Sharepoint Hosted App

Tags: office-365, sharepoint-hosted-app

I have created a sharepoint hosted app to create a custom action like Create Zip Button.

I have created custom action for ribbon.
In first Step I selected Hostweb and select custom action scope as Document Library.
In second step it asks where does a button control navigate to ?

It shows URL of Default.aspx Page.
Now Is it compulsory to give Page URL.

My requirement is not to redirect a Page.
Instead of redirecting a page when user click on button from custom ribbon from document Library I need List of all files and to create a zip.

What to do to achieve this?
Is it possible using sharepoint hosted app?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create a custom ribbon button which doesn't require page redirect. Check below:

```
    function RibbonValidation() {
    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
        try {
            var pm = SP.Ribbon.PageManager.get_instance();
            pm.add_ribbonInited(function () {
                CreateRibbon();
            });
            var ribbon = null;
            try {
                ribbon = pm.get_ribbon();
            }
            catch (e) { }
            if (!ribbon) {
                if (typeof (_ribbonStartInit) == "function")
                    _ribbonStartInit(_ribbon.initialTabId, false, null);
            }
            else {
                CreateRibbon();
            }
        } catch (e)
        { }
    }, "sp.ribbon.js");
}
function CreateRibbon() {
    var Ribbonhtml = document.createElement('div');
    Ribbonhtml.setAttribute("id", "CustomRibbon");
    Ribbonhtml.innerHTML = "<div><a href='#' onclick=\"LoadApps()\" ><img src='../_layouts/images/NoteBoard_32x32.png' /></a><br/>SP Add-in\'s</div>";
    var ribbon = SP.Ribbon.PageManager.get_instance().get_ribbon();
    if (ribbon) {
        var tab = new CUI.Tab(ribbon, 'GlobalRibbon.Tab', 'Option', 'Option', 'GlobalRibbon.Tab.Command', false, '', null);
        ribbon.addChildAtIndex(tab, 1);
        var group = new CUI.Group(ribbon, 'GlobalRibbon.Tab.Group', 'Custom Ribbon', 'Global Ribbon Example', 'GlobalRibbon.Group.Command', null);
        tab.addChild(group);
    }
    SelectRibbonTab('GlobalRibbon.Tab', false);
    document.getElementById("GlobalRibbon.Tab.Group").childNodes[0].childNodes[0].appendChild(Ribbonhtml);
    SelectRibbonTab('Ribbon.Read', true);
    window.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", RibbonValidation, false);
}
function LoadApps() {
//add your custom logic to get items from SharePoint list and zip the files
//here i am getting list of all apps installed in the site collection and showing them in a dialog.
    clientcontext = SP.ClientContext.get_current()
    currentWeb = clientcontext.get_web();
    appinstancesList = SP.AppCatalog.getAppInstances(clientcontext, currentWeb);
    clientcontext.load(appinstancesList);
    clientcontext.executeQueryAsync(Success, fail);
}
function DialogApps(stringHtml) {
    var element = document.createElement('div');
    element.innerHTML = stringHtml;
    SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', {
        html: element,
        title: "SharePoint Add-in",
        allowMaximize: false,
        showClose: true,
        autoSize: true
    });
}
function Success() {
    var stringHtml = '';
    var list = appinstancesList.getEnumerator();
    while (list.moveNext()) {
        var current = list.get_current();

        stringHtml += '<div>' + current.get_title() + '</br><a href=\'' + _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + ((_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl.indexOf('/', _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl.length - 1) !== -1) ? '' : '/') + '_layouts/15/appredirect.aspx?instance_id={' + current.get_id() + '}\'>Link</a></div>';
    }
    DialogApps(stringHtml);
}
function fail(sender, args) {
    alert(args.get_message());
}
```

Reference - [Header & Footer SharePoint Add-In with custom ribbon button](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.EmbedJavaScript.HeaderFooter)

Comment: Is It possible with Share Point Hosted App and Office 365 ?

Comment: I only want to use JSOM not Code behind. Is this one will suitable to me ? How to apply this with share point hosted app visual studio project?

Comment: Yes this is pure JSOM code and it's suitable for your requirement. Check the link and see the implementation of PnP.